# price per kilo in virtuemart 2

Tags: virtuemart

I need to set up a price per kilo (for tomatoes),

is there a way to do it directly in the admin ?

Do I need to code something? if so, can you give a place to start , I'm sure this must exist but I was unable to find it.

Answer (score 0):

I'll try this http://extensions.virtuemart.net/extensions-virtuemart-2/custom-size-detail